# Joomla JDatabase Query inserts empty row

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I am developing a simple guestbook for Joomla 1.7.

If I try to insert a new message JDatabase inserts a empty row and I don't know why.

Here the table structure

```
  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `#__agb_messages`;

  CREATE TABLE `#__agb_messages` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `message` TEXT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
  );
```

Here the code i am using to insert the new row and load the existing rows

```
    public function getMessages() {

    $db = JFactory::getDBO();

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r(JRequest::get('post'));
    echo "</pre>";

    $post = JRequest::get('post');

    if (
            !empty($post['name'])
         && !empty($post['message'])
            )
    {
        $query = 'INSERT INTO #__agb_messages SET name="'.(string)$post['name'].'" AND message="'.(string)$post['message'].'"';
        $db->setQuery($query);
        echo $db->getQuery();
        $db->query();
        echo $db->getErrorMsg();
    }

    $query = 'SELECT * FROM #__agb_messages ORDER BY id DESC';
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $messages = $db->loadObjectList();

    return $messages;
}
```

This is what i get

```
  Array
  (
  [0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 1
        [name] => 0
        [message] => 
    )
  )
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why Joomla 1.7?

Comment: I am doing that for a friend of mine and he has to finish his project site (for school). And the exercise/mission/job is to develop a guestbook for joomla 1.7

Comment: Ah ok fair enough. Well I'm better at trial and error that looking at code and finding errors, so if you would like to send me the guestbook, I will try to find the problem when I get home.

Answer (score 1):

hi check the inser query format...

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3,...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)
```

This is the correct syntax for `INSERT` query.

- Don't confuse with Update Query format :)

Comment: I don't know what difference it make because it is a valid syntax, see the documentation of mysql. Anyway, it doesn't make a difference. 'INSERT INTO #__agb_messages (name,message) VALUES ("'.$post['name'].'","'.$post['message'].'")'

Comment: And i am telling you that you should look at the documentation for that. To use SET is ok and it works. I always use SET in small INSERT Querys. ... Sorry that it sounds so hard :P

Comment: ok, bit sorry to you basith, it realy does make a difference! =) I don't know what the difference it is but after a small puse, it worked with the "insert ... values" syntax. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Consider also using the `JDatabase` class from Joomla to do the insert ;)

```
public function insertObject (
        $table
        &$object
        $keyName=NULL
)
```

http://docs.joomla.org/JDatabase::insertObject/1.6

I guess that it's also available for Joomla 1.7

Answer (score 0):

Extend Jtable and use the built in methods from the Joomla API,